# Volume with variable host location in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to share my mysql data directory with a docker container. The goal is to be able to configure the shared folder location with an environment variable on the host machine.

Using docker compose, the relevant portion of my docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
data:
    image: yappabe/data
    volumes:
        - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR}:/var/lib/mysql
    tty: true
```

When running the container, I get this error:

```
Creating docker_data_1
ERROR: . includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed
```

Running `echo $MYSQL_DATA_DIR` in the terminal returns the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this issue comment](http://ENTRYPOINT%20/tmp/folder-$Version/sample.sh%20start), you would need to declare the environment variable in your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
data:
    image: yappabe/data
    environment:
        - MYSQL_DATA_DIR
```

The [OP jdp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324307/jdp) confirms a volume path ([as supported/illustrated here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1867)) can then use the environment variable, as in `${MYSQL_DATA_DIR}:/var/lib/mysql`.